# Updating node version using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm-install, nvm

I want to upgrade my node version to 16.15.1 I am using nvm for this but getting error please help me resolving it. Here is image showing error attached[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first do a clean reinstall of the package manager, a python dependency is missing. Then you can run `nvm install --lts` which would be the v16 you would like.

Comment: How should I reinstall package manager